# Как указать в интепретаторе версию php?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains

Нужно указать в интепретаторе версию php, но не знаю, как указать путь, подскажите! )

Answer (score 1):

CTRL + ALT + S -> Languages & Frameworks -> PHP

Comment: в поле interpreter у меня пусто,там нужно указать путь,а какой не знаю

Comment: @Серёжа Сухинин, в консоли выполнить `which php` на линуксе, `where php` на винде.

Comment: @Etki,вот что выдает
C:\WINDOWS\system32\where.exe php ����������: �� 㤠���� ���� 䠩�� �� ������� 蠡�����.
Process finished with exit code 1 at 15:20:59. Execution time: 103 ms.

Comment: Скачайте и положите куда вам нужно. Это поле не обязательно указывать, просто выберите необходимую версию.